# Problem rendering R Plots output to png device in azure app service

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, r.net

I am working on migrating my on-premises asp.net app to azure app service. My app renders R plots as a PNG using R.net. I am packaging R software as a folder(not as installation) in my publish and updating R.net environment variables to use R libraries in that folder. This setup is working in an on-premises windows server:
[image]
While trying to render this in Azure app service using the same parameters as on-prem, it renders an error. The below specifies output at 300dpi:
[image: Exception when rendering at dpi 300]

If the output resolution is changed to 280dpi, the png image renders but is missing lots of legends and lines:
[image: Partial png render when using output dpi 280]

I tried setting type = "cario" for png device but not able to draw complete plot.
Other things tried:

- Setting the output to a bitmap. Also renders a partial image, but different issues from the PNG. It renders the plot, but tiles of the image are missing, particularly on the right and bottom of the image [image: Bitmap Rendering]
- Setting the output to a pdf. Renders a complete image, but not in the format we want (PNG) [image: PDF rendering]

Any suggestions on rendering R plots from azure app service are well appreciated.